# why do I encounter these errors and fail to create my react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, installation

when I try to create a react.js web application on VScode using "npm" it return these errors:

```
npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! errno ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! network Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/webpack-dev-server: Socket timeout
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Al-Harith\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-05-07T00_29_10_990Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting my_project/ from C:\Users\Al-Harith\Desktop
Done.
```

I tried changing different networks for connectivity enhancement but to no avail. I’m looking forward to hearing the right solutions from the experts.

Comment: Try accessing https://registry.npmjs.org/webpack-dev-server from a browser and check the response. Something is blocking this domain

Answer (score 0):

Do this at first:  `npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/`

Then try again to run: `npx create-react-app [your_app_name]`